# Assimp Export (C++) FBX file makes too much size

Tags: c++, fbx, assimp

I am creating an FBX file through Assimp which makes too much size.

Sample source code:

```
scene->mRootNode = new aiNode();

scene->mMaterials = new aiMaterial*[1];
scene->mMaterials[0] = nullptr;
scene->mNumMaterials = 1;

scene->mMaterials[0] = new aiMaterial();

scene->mMeshes = new aiMesh*[numMesh];
scene->mNumMeshes = numMesh;
scene->mRootNode->mMeshes = new unsigned int[numMesh];  
scene->mRootNode->mNumMeshes = numMesh;
```

Please let me know if anyone has encountered the same problem.

Comment: You are not generating an FBX-file, you are trying to generate a simple Assimp--based scene and export it as an FBX. Is that right?

Comment: And you have export it as a FBX-file?